# How to use DTO projection without using foreign key association?

Tags: java, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have three tables where `ItemTag` acts as an intermediate table to relate the other two tables.

```kotlin
data class Item(
    val id: Int,
    val title: String
)

data class ItemTag(
    val id: Int,
    val itemId: Int,
    val tagId: Int
)

data class Tag(
    val id: Int,
    val title: String
)
```

Then there is a projection DTO.

```kotlin
interface ItemDTO {
    val id: Int
    val title: String
    val tag: List<String>
}
```

Then use JPQL custom query:

```kotlin
@Query(
    """
    select
    e.title as title,
    e.id as id,
    t.title as tag
    from Item e
    left join ItemTag it on e.id = it.itemId
    left join Tag t on it.tagId = t.id
    where e.id in (:ids)
    """
)
fun queryById(@Param("ids") ids: List<Int>): List<ItemDTO>
```

But this code does not work properly, the `tag` field cannot be queried.

What is the correct way to do it, note: I don't want to use foreign key associations, that is, I don't use annotations like `@OneToMany`